# ModuleNotFoundError when running pytest after moving the application directory for Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, fastapi

Using Python 3.8, I made a functional project using FastAPI. With the structure I outline below, I placed all the elements of my project in an "app" folder so I could create a Docker image.

```
├── app/
|     └── sdk/
|          └── __init__.py
|          └── sdk.py
|          └── schemas.py
|          └── exceptions.py
|     └── api/
|          └── __init__.py
|          └── services.py
|     └── tests/
|          └── __init__.py
|          └── test_live_sdk.py
|     └── main.py
├── DockerFile
├── Pipfile
```

After debugging and renaming imports, my project works correctly when I run the docker image, however, when I want to run the tests navigating from my console (Not from Docker), this is, inside the `app` folder, and then running `pytest tests/test_live_sdk.py`, as I did before, I get the following error:

```
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app/tests/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from app import sdk
app/sdk/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from . import sdk
app/sdm/sdk.py:1: in <module>
    from sdk import schemas, exceptions, constants
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sdk'
```

Previously, in order to import those directories from another package, what I did was to import them inside the `__init__.py`, in the following ways:

```
# sdk/__init__.py
import sdk
```

```
# api/__init__.py
from . import *
```

Afterwards, I assumed that my package already recognized this import. This seemed to work before modifying the parent directory, but no longer. I tried to add `app.`, but this also doesn't work either.

Is it possible to run the tests independently of docker? That is, navigating directly to the app folder and then run `pytest <test.py>`, or this can only be executed once Docker already recognizes which is the working directory?

**In other words, how can I access the modules that pytest fails to recognize?**

I recognize that python imports are one of the subjects that confuse me the most, so I greatly appreciate any guidance. I'm sure the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

Plase provide the contents of your Dockerfile and the Pipfile.

Usually the standard for writing Dockerfiles for Python is that, you have a

requirements.txt

For your case it could be something like :

```
cat requirements.txt 
uvicorn[standard]==0.18.3
fastapi==0.45.0
urllib3==1.22
cx_freeze==6.0b1
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-cov==2.5.1
pytest-dependency==0.2
```

And then the Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD["pytest", "tests/test_live_sdk.py"]
```

Or something like that... I will edit with more appropriate configurations once you provide Dockerfile and Pipfile.